# Suitable web framework in ASP.NET for real time web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a Windows real time application. Now I want to convert this application into a web application in ASP.NET. I want suggestions about the web framework that I can use. Which is suitable? I have ideas of ASP web form , MVC. And also open source JavaScript library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR supports real time communication between client and sever

http://www.asp.net/signalr